# Entity Framework same primary key value error when saving changes to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

In my program, I'm using Entity Framework and added a table to my `.edmx` model. I mapped the insert, update, and delete functions to only one stored procedure, my update procedure, since it is the only procedure I will be using on this table. In my program, I loop through a bunch of users getting values and adding them to the entity before finally saving the changes.

Start loop

```
var newGroup = new ru_Groups();

newGroup.adsPath = adsPath; 
newGroup.DisplayName = displayName; 
newGroup.Domain = domain; 
newGroup.AccountName = accountName;
newGroup.Email = email;
newGroup.GroupType = groupType;

UserEntities.ru_Groups.Add(newGroup);
```

end loop

```
UserEntities.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is when I save the changes I get this error

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error
>   occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be
>   in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: Saving or accepting
>   changes failed because more than one entity of type
>   'AD.Data.ru_Groups' have the same primary key value. Ensure that
>   explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that
>   database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the
>   database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer
>   for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the
>   'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or
>   'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.

Why is this happening? The ID `StoredGeneratedPattern` property is set to `Identity`, however the stored procedure which I've mapped to the `Update` function does not require an ID as a parameter, let alone a unique ID.

Thank you

Comment: you say the `StoredGeneratorPattern' is set to Identity, but have you confirmed that the underlying sql svr db column is set as an Identity column?  If the db is not setup, .Net doesn't generate the ID itself.

Comment: An update procedure that doesn't require an Id? If you map stored procedures to CUD actions in Entity Framework, these procedures are supposed to have strict signatures. I wonder how you can even map only one sproc to the three CUD actions. It would be useful for your question to see the sproc. For one, the insert sproc should return a generated Id value.